# Android: How to tell if the ok key of the keyboard was pressed?

Tags: android, keyboard

Is there a way to know when the user hits the ok key on the keyboard?

Comment: The key that sometimes says send or go when your using a messenger app or a browser respectively.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Call `setOnEditorActionListener()` on your `EditText`, and your `OnEditorActionListener` will be called with `onEditorAction()` when the user presses the IME action key.

Note that not all IMEs have such a key, so do not count on this.

Answer (score 0):

Try `KeyEvent.FLAG_EDITOR_ACTION`

From: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/KeyEvent.html#FLAG_EDITOR_ACTION